# Getting a BlueMix app through a firewall

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am currently working on a java back end server that I am deploying to bluemix. It is a standard web app, built out with maven and hits a mounted data base. Standard stuff.

The question becomes is that two of the end points that I am using are hitting services that exist on networks that have their own firewall. 
Now if I deploy the application to a server that is punched through the firewalls, all is well. However on bluemix where I am not punched through these firewalls, I often get 401 errors.

Does anyone know of a way to pass these credentials when doing a post or get so that I can authenticate through the firewall, and then authenticate through the service?

Thank you all.

Comment: maybe you can give more details about your configuration or/and code samples to allow people to better help you out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the following Bluemix services to connect your application running on Bluemix to your on-premise application/database behind the firewall:

- Secure Gateway
- Cloud Integration

With Secure Gateway you can create a secure tunnel between Bluemix application and your on-premise application. The official documentation is available [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/index.html), but there is also an excellent article in the link below to start with this service:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/03/27/bluemix-secure-gateway-yes-can-get/

Alternatively the Cloud Integration service documentation is available [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/index.html).

Comment: Also the Statica Bluemix service to give the app a static IP could be useful here.

Comment: Don't use Cloud Integration. Secure Gateway is much more reliable, better supported, and being actively developed.